# How to create multiple sorting buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The design of the project I'm working has three buttons used for sorting of the items on the page.

[image]

The first one sorts items by price, second one by availability and the third one by date.
The designer wants me to create them so that when the button is clicked once it should change the color, indicating that items are sorted, and when it is clicked again, the arrow should change the direction, indicating that the sorting order has been reversed.

How do I do this? I tried with radio button labels and hidden radio indicators but radio buttons can't be clicked twice.

Comment: What have you already tried? Please provide the markup and code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a very useful plugin for things like this. 
Checkout http://isotope.metafizzy.co/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I ended up using the radio buttons anyway, but I added the script that toggles the button arrow up and down by toggling between asc and desc classes on the active button.
Earlier I forgot to mention that I'm using bootstrap 4 toggle states (data-toggle="buttons").

```
<div class="sort-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <p>Sortieren:</p><label class="btn btn-secondary sortable active asc" id="sort-by-price">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked> PREIS
  </label><label class="btn btn-secondary sortable" id="sort-by-availability">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off" checked> VERFÜGBARKEIT
  </label><label class="btn btn-secondary sortable" id="sort-by-date">
    <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"> DATUM
  </label>
</div>
```

Note: sort-group's child element's closing tag and the subsequent child element's starting tag are on the same line to avoid the blank space between them due to display: inline block.

SCSS:

```
.sort-group {
        p,
        label.btn {
                margin-bottom: 0;
        }
        p {
                color: 3d3d3d;
                display: inline-block;
                font-size: 14px;
                margin-right: 24px; 
                @media (max-width: 767px) {
                        display: block;
                        margin-top: 13px;
                        margin-bottom: 13px;
                }
        }
        label.btn{  
            background: url('../images/icons/down.svg') right 16px center no-repeat;        
            border-radius: 40px;
            font-size: 12px;
            font-weight: bold;
            height: 26px;
            line-height: 25px;
            margin-right: 12px;
            padding: 0 16px;
            text-align: left;
            -webkit-user-select: none;
            -moz-user-select: none;
            -ms-user-select: none;
            user-select: none;
            &.active {
                    color: #fff;
                    background-color: #333;
                    border-color: #333;
                    outline: none;
            }
            &:last-of-type {
                    margin-right: 0;
            }
            @media (max-width: 767px) {
                    display: block;
                    margin-bottom: 13px;
            }
        }
        label.asc{
                background: url('../images/icons/down-white.svg') right 16px center no-repeat;
        }
        label.desc{
                background: url('../images/icons/up-white.svg') right 16px center no-repeat;
        }
        #sort-by-price {
            width: 93px;
        }
        #sort-by-availability {
            width: 164px;
        }
        #sort-by-date{
            width: 101px;
        }   
}
```

jquery:

```
    $(".sortable").click(function(){
        var o = $(this).hasClass('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
        $('.sortable').removeClass('asc').removeClass('desc');
        $(this).addClass(o);
    });
```